# How do I add a new column with a specific word to a file in linux?

Tags: linux, character, cpu-word

I have a file with one column containing 2059 ID numbers.
I want to add a second column with the word 'pop1' for all the 2059 ID numbers.
 The second column will just mean that the ID number belongs to population 1.

> How can I do this is linux using awk or sed?

The file currently has one column which looks like this

```
45958 
480585 
308494
```

I want it to look like:

```
45958 pop1
480585 pop1
308494 pop1
```

Comment: `awk '{print $0 "\tpop"}' file > newFile && mv newFile file` . The `\t` gives you a tab char, but you can easily replace it with a space char (no \ char required). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, and it doesn't use sed or awk, but I would do that:

```
while read -r line; do echo ""$line" pop1" >> newfile; done < test
```

This command will append stuff in the file 'newfile', so be sure that it's empty or it doesn't exist before executing the command.

Here is the resource I used, on reading a file line by line : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution.

```
$ perl -lpi -e '$_ .= " pop1"' your-file-name
```

Command line options:

- -l : remove newline from input and replace it on output
- -p : put each line of input into `$_` and print `$_` at the end of each iteration
- -i : in-place editing (overwrite the input file)
- -e : run this code for each line of the input

The code (`$_ .= " pop1"`) just appends your string to the input record.

Comment: My upvote will not be visible because I don't have the required credentials.